# click handler not setting local storage in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Hello all I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function a() {
    console.log("hover in")
    var type = "type-a";
    localStorage.setItem('type', type);
  };

  function b(){
       console.log("hover out")
    var type = "unknown";
    localStorage.setItem('type', "unknown");
  }


  $(".type-link").each(function(index, value) {
    $(value).hover(a, b);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="type-link"> link </a>
```

The idea of the code is on hover of a link i want to set the type property with a string value, for simplification purposes i have just referenced a hard coded variable with the value of unknown.

I am seeing some unusual behaviour in that i can see the logs of hover in and hover out but i cannot see the type property of local storage being set.

i am seeing this behaviour in both chrome and firefox.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the code where you retrieve `type` from local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a class="type-link" href="#"> link1 </a>
<button id="getData">Show Data</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function a() {
    console.log("hover in")
    var type = "unknown";
    localStorage.setItem('type', type);
  };

  function b(){
       console.log("hover out")
    var type = "unknown";
    localStorage.setItem('type', "unknown");

  }

  $(".type-link").each(function(index, value) {
 // debugger;
    $(value).hover(a, b);
  });

  $("#getData").click(function(){
    alert(localStorage.getItem('type'));
  });
});
```

Refer this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/60/)

Answer (score 0):

That code working for me. Check it on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omLkv7p8/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function a() {
    console.log("hover in")
    var type = "type-a";
    localStorage.setItem('type', type);
    updateStorage()
  };

  function b(){
    console.log("hover out")
    var type = "unknown";
    localStorage.setItem('type', "unknown");
    updateStorage()
  }
  
  function updateStorage () {
    $('#local').text(localStorage.getItem('type'))
  }


  $(".type-link").each(function(index, value) {
    $(value).hover(a, b);
  });
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<a class="type-link"> link </a>
<p id="local"></p>
```